# Fill select in html from array sent by nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Im a greenhorn to Node/JS/Ajax and all that stuff.
i have an app that sends an array response. i want to fill an select from that array in my html. here is what i have so far:

app.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/public/html/index.html');
});

app.get('/collectionnames', function(req, res) {
    var collectionnames = [];
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error");
        } else {
            console.log("Connected to MongoDB to get collections...");
        }
        var db = client.db('mydb');
        db.listCollections().toArray(function (err,collections) {
                collections.forEach(function(collection){       
                    var elem = new Object();
                    if (collection.name !== "system.indexes"){
                    //console.log(collection.name);
                    elem = collection.name;
                    collectionnames.push(elem);
                    };
                });
                console.log("got collections...")
                console.log(collectionnames);
                res.send(collectionnames);
            });
        });
    });
```

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
 </head<
<body onload="getCollections()">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/test.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

my test.js

```
function getCollections() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/collectionnames',
    })  
//    .done(function(data) {
//            alert(data.join(' '));
//   })
}
```

This is working so far as i receive the array/values with the test.js and can see it with "alert(data.join(' '));" What i want now is to have a select form in my index.html that is feeded with/as option from the array (data) but i dont know how.

May i please someone to give some help?

Comment: All the AJAX and node.js stuff is completely irrelevant. You only need to show us the output of `console.log(data)`. Constructing an option element is easy: `$('<option>').val(1).text('blah')`

Comment: Creating elements with jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have this:

```
<select id="location-select" class="" name="" hidden></select>
```

Your JS will look like this:

```
const locationArr = data; //your array data
let locationSelector = document.querySelector("#location-select");

if(locationArr.length){
  locationSelector.hidden = false;
}
locationArr.forEach((location, index) => {
    let opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = location.id;
    opt.innerHTML = location.location_name;
    locationSelector.appendChild(opt);
});
```

**EDIT:**
Make the following changes:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
 </head<
<body onload="getCollections()">
<select id="my-select" class="" name="" hidden></select>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/test.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
function getCollections() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/collectionnames',
    })
   .done(function(data) {
           alert(data.join(' '));
           generateSelect(data);
  })
}

function generateSelect(dataArr){
     let mySelect = document.querySelector("#my-select");

     if(dataArr.length){
       mySelect.hidden = false;
     }
     dataArr.forEach((obj, index) => {
         let opt = document.createElement("option");
         opt.value = obj.id;
         opt.innerHTML = obj.name;
         mySelect.appendChild(opt);
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I put the select in index.html and the JS in test.js but the drop down stays empty. I tried to put it all in index.html with the same result.

Comment: @MaikelNight This is just how you generate it. If you are combining with your need, then make a function of this js code, and call it when you get data from API.

Comment: I set in JSFiddle a static array which looks like mine and edited opt.value = location; opt.innerHTML = location; and it works as expected. But i cant get it work in my code with my array (if i set it static by copy and paste code from jsfiddle it also works). I believe its about test.js calls and receive an array onload of index.html and i dont know how i can implement or better call a function then that processes the array.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check Edit and let me know if it makes sense or not.

Comment: Makes sense and thanks a lot. I edited obj.id and obj.name to just "obj" because my array is only a list. It works like i expetcted it now!!! If you have the time and feel like it: what exactely happens at "generateSelect(data);" and "generateSelect(dataArr)"?

Comment: I'm happy that it worked.
And if you are asking about the variable name then, data and dataArr are just variable names, you can use anything.
For instance this is also fine: "generateSelect(data);" and "generateSelect(data)".